# error in convertion raisevent

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Hi I tried to convert this using the web free tool conversion. My problem is the raisevent and below is the script that I converted from c# to vb. Tried to run it the error is below first string of code...

```
 GoogleMapForASPNet1.PushpinDrag += New GoogleMapForASPNet.PushpinDragHandler(AddressOf OnPushpinDrag)
```

'Heres the event handler for PushpinDrag event

```
Private Sub OnPushpinDrag(pID As String)           
    lblPushpin1.Text = 
        "(" + GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Points(pID).Latitude.ToString() + "," 
        + GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Points(pID).Longitude.ToString() + ")"
End Sub
```

Hoping for anyone to help me with this scenario

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Incidentally VB uses `&` for concatenating strings.

Comment: @OneFineDay: Actually, VB uses both '&' and '+' for string concatenation (gotta love VB). '&' is a dedicated concatenation operator, while '+' does string concatenation in certain contexts.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, I am pointing out which one is the correct one. `+` makes the compiler guess what you want, `&` tells the compiler exactly what it should be doing.

Comment: @OneFineDay: Yes - I agree that '&' is far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to this:

```
AddHandler GoogleMapForASPNet1.PushpinDrag, AddressOf OnPushpinDrag
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx)